# Need help in understanding Java tutorial on Generics

Tags: java, generics

I was reading a Java tutorial from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html). I am having trouble understanding a simple line.

Tutorial says declaration of `Collections.emptyList` is:

> `static <T> List<T> emptyList();`

So if we write `List<String> listOne = Collections.emptyList();`, it works as the Java compiler is able to infer the type parameter, as the returned value should be of type `List<String>`.

Now consider a method: `void processStringList(List<String> stringList)`. Now it states:

> processStringList(Collections.emptyList()); The Java SE 7 compiler
>   generates an error message similar to the following:
>
> List<'Object> cannot be converted to List<'String>
>
> The compiler requires
>   a value for the type argument T so it starts with the value Object.
>   Consequently, the invocation of Collections.emptyList returns a value
>   of type `List<Object>`, which is incompatible with the method
>   processStringList

Now what do they mean by: *so it starts with the value Object*? I mean start doing what?

Comment: It simply means that it infers that `T` is `Object`.

Comment: FYI, it explains further down that they've fixed this in Java 8, so unless you're working legacy code then it's basically irrelevant. `processStringList(Collections.emptyList())` infers the type perfectly well.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yep, I said "it explains further down [the page]"

Comment: In addition to what is stated in the previous comments, I would like to clarify that the line is actually processed as List<String> listOne = Collections.<String>emptyList(); your can add the type parameter before the method name, and it will work as you expect it to even when used as a method argument.

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically this is about the capabilities of the compiler. In other words: to a certain degree, the "amount" of possible type inference is an implementation detail.

With Java 7, you sometimes have to use type helpers/hints/witnesses, where you would go `Collections.<String>emptyList()` to tell the compiler about that missing part.

Later implementations of the compiler improved the situation that you can almost always go with `Collections.emptyList()`.

Regarding `The compiler requires a value for the type argument T so it starts with the value Object.` ... that is actually quite simple: the java compiler has to implement an algorithm, that finally, infers a specific type. Giving some pseudo-code, that might look like:

```
Class<?> inferType(SomeSyntaxTree construct) {
```

I am just using `Class` here to indicate that the algorithm will return something that resembles a known type. Now, that method *could* be implemented like this:

```
 Class<?> inferedType = Object.class
 while (whatever) {
   refine inferedType
 }
 return inferedType
```

In other words: that is a very common approach when you "search" for some value: you initialize with the "most generic" value (in the Java type system, that would be Object.class), and then you see if that generic value can be refined by applying whatever algorithm.

In our case, the refinement might end up in figuring "the most specific type that can be used is `String`", but if no further refinement is possible, then you end up with your "initial default", being `Object`.

Comment: They are referred to as type *witnesses* in the tutorial (although I can't find the term in JLS).

Comment: @AndyTurner Deja vu. I keep forgetting the correct name. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: That's language specification rather than just changes in the compiler. (I think. There have been bugs.)

Answer (score 1):

The statement

> `processStringList(Collections.emptyList());`

works fine in Java 8 (I'm assuming above 8 as well). The compiler in this case is smart enough to infer the types by checking what is the expected argument type for the method.

In older versions, when compiler sees no explicit return type (as in `List<String> listOne = Collections.emptyList();`), it by default infers `<T>` to `java.lang.Object`. But note that `List<Object>` and `List<String>` are not compatible.

You can declare the method like `void processString(List<? super String> list)` to avoid the error.